# 3 Subqueries and joins help required

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

[image]I am trying to exclude users that have no entry on a trip table but include them if the are not expired users (ie modifieddate not over 13 months old)

the modifieddate field is on the user table

I can't figure out a way to allow the following be returned

- User on a trip over 13 months old
- User not on any trip but user is expired

but not return

- User on trip in the last 13 months
- User not on any trip but user not expired

I have included my code below. any help appreciated

```
DECLARE @dt datetime, @months int

SET @dt = GETDATE()
SET @months = -13

select distinct app.* 
from appuser app
inner join  
(
    select user_id from appuser where user_id  not in    (
                                --Get app users that have been on any approved trips in the last x months
                                select distinct app.user_id
                                from  appuser app
                                join trip_user tu 
                                on tu.user_id = app.user_id
                                join trip t
                                on t.trip_id = tu.trip_id                               
                                where
                                trip_date between DATEADD(MONTH, -13, GETDATE()) and  Getdate()
                                    -- approved or completed trip
                                and trip_status_id in (2,3)
                                )                                   

    ) as PassNotOnTripInLast13Mons 
    on app.user_id = PassNotOnTripInLast13Mons.user_id
        left join
    (
        select distinct app.user_id from appuser app
            join trip_user tu 
            on tu.user_id = app.user_id
            join trip t
            on t.trip_id = tu.trip_id
            where
            trip_date > DATEADD(MONTH, -13, GETDATE())          
    ) as PassOnTripOver13Mons        
    on app.user_id = PassOnTripOver13Mons.user_id
    left join (
        select distinct user_id 
        from appuser  
        where DATEDIFF(MONTH, ModifiedDate ,  GETDATE()) > 13
        ) as PassOnSystemOver13Mons
    on app.user_id = PassOnSystemOver13Mons.user_id 
where 
--is a passanger        
isPassenger = 1 
--user does not have an unmet need
and app.user_id not in (select passenger_id from unmet_needs where passenger_id = app.user_id)
-- don't redo a passange alread obfusticated
and obfusticated = 0 
and isNTA = 0
and isTCUDispatcher = 0
and isProviderUser = 0
and isDriver = 0
```

Comment: Is modified date required (not null)?

Comment: yes modified date is a not null field

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best understanding of your requirements: you need to return users who have either gone on any trip, or been modified in the last thirteen months.  You also have an undocumented requirement in your code to only include passengers who have not been obfusticated, and only count trips that have been approved (`trip_status_id in (2,3)`).

Based on those requirements, I think the following simplified code would do what you are trying to accomplish:

```
select app.* 
from 
    appuser app
     left join 
    tripuser tu on 
        app.user_id = tu.user_id 
     left join 
     trip on 
        tu.trip_id = trip.trip_id 
        and trip_status_id in (2,3) -- approved trip
        and trip_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, GETDATE())
WHERE 
      (
        trip.trip_id is null and
        app.ModifiedDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, GETDATE())
      )
    --is a passenger        
    and isPassenger = 1 
    --user does not have an unmet need
    and app.user_id not in (select passenger_id from unmet_needs where passenger_id = app.user_id)
    -- don't redo a passange alread obfusticated
    and obfusticated = 0 
    and isNTA = 0
    and isTCUDispatcher = 0
    and isProviderUser = 0
    and isDriver = 0
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I essentially have to return passengers that are either on trips older than 13 months or on the system for more than 13 months but NOT return passengers that have been on recent trips (<13 months) and NOT return passangers that are not on any trip & not expired (>13months)

Comment: OK, please review the changes - I believe this will return users who have not been on a trip in at least thirteen months, and who have not been modified during that same time window. Is that correct?

Comment: thanks again, appreciate your time. Im away from the db now but i think now it will as you said return just users who have not been on any trip in at least thirteen months AND who have have also not been modified in 13 months. however i need a resultset that has all of the following 1.users on trips over 13 months old. 2.users not on any trips but last modified over 13 months ago. while also ensuring NOT to return 1. users not on any trips but last modified within 13 months and 2. users on trips within last 13 months    thanks again.